# What is so special about being multiples of 22, 47 and 56 for standard capacitor and resistor values?

Tags: capacitor

Why is that special numbers instead of multiples of 10?
Same goes with some resistor values of 47, 560 220 ohm ect.?

Where and why is this issue originate from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values are chosen due to the fact that when they are plotted on a log-scale there is a linear progression in values.

See:

[Why are the "common" resistors and capacitors rated the way they are?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/why-are-the-common-resistors-and-capacitors-rated-the-way-they-are)

and

[What is the reason that the value "47" is so popular in electrical engineering?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67975/what-is-the-reason-that-the-value-47-is-so-popular-in-electrical-engineering/67984#67984)

for more information.