# Why wierd capacitance values

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, manufacturing

Why are capacitors available with values like 378 µfarad and 0.22 farad which have prime numbers like 11 and 7 in factorization instead of values like 375 µfarad and 0.2 and 0.25 farad which are nicer in factoring and addition?

What makes the manufacture of former advantageous than latter?

Comment: Can you give a link to a 378 uF capacitor? That's a value I've never heard of.

Comment: https://www.petervis.com/electronics/Electrolytic_Capacitor_Values/Electrolytic_Capacitor_Values.html

Comment: Also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/159320/6334

Comment: Thanks, got my answer

Comment: A lot of "why" questions are hard to answer because it can sometimes be an industry standard to which many people would not know about. (If you got your answer, feel free to answer your own question down in the answer box for future reference for other people with the same question... It'll also help close this question as well. Yes, you can answer your own question, that's perfectly legal on this website.)

Comment: @KingDuken, when the question is a duplicate of an earlier post, it doesn't make sense to self-answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Fair point, now I see the duplicate :)

Comment: Logarithmically, many of these values become uniformly spaced, ensuring the designer can find values within +-20% or +-10% or +-5% or +-1% of the ideal resistor and capacitor value. Thus AC-coupled circuits can set precise low-pass corners (such as 20,000Hz) and precise high-pass corners (such as 50Hz).