# Why are 22pF capacitors so common?

Tags: capacitor, theory

I've noticed that many circuits use 22pF capacitors. For instance, the Arduino uses them to ground the oscillator pins of its AtMega328. Many tutorials call for [exactly this value](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Arduino_Scuola/build-a-simple-dac-for-your-arduino-4c00bd) for simple circuits.

Why is specifically 22 pF so common? Why not 20 or 25, which are arguably "rounder" numbers?

Comment: Because 22 is one of the E-12 numbers.  I could write a looong answer but you can find it all in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers#E12)

Comment: [This question and its answers go into some detail.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/why-are-the-common-resistors-and-capacitors-rated-the-way-they-are)

Comment: @Oldfart Thank you. I was hesitant to ask because I was not sure if this was a good question. However the existence of that page reassures me that this was actually a great question with a bit of history and lot engineering.

Comment: Thank you JRE, yes, that is also extremely relevant.

Comment: [What about 47 pF or 4k7 or 470 ohms](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67975/what-is-the-reason-that-the-value-47-is-so-popular-in-electrical-engineering/67984#67984)

Comment: I do question the comment that the Arduino uses the 22pF capacitors "on the ATMega328 ground pins". The ground pins of the MCU are just part of the ground rail for the whole circuit and the 22pF capacitors are in crystal oscillator circuit happen to also connect to ground.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Corrected, thank you.